# jQuery: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).click is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Not sure where I'm exactly going wrong here - I'm trying to simply hide a certain div when another one is clicked. Here is my jQuery (placed at the very bottom of the .html file):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".card__container--closed").click(function () {
            $(".hide__overlay").hide();
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="hide__overlay">
    <p class="card__subtitle overlay card-overlay">NEWS</p>
</div>
<div id="card" class="card">
    ...some SVG image thing here...
</div>
```

However, for some reason I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).click is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>
```

I'm using `jQuery 3.2.1`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of your problems are due to the fact that you're using jQuery 3 and lots of things have been removed since jQuery 2. Remember, major version numbers mean they're allowed to include breaking changes. For more about what's different in jQuery 3.0+, please read the [jQuery 3.0 Upgrade Guide](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/).

First, you don't need `$(document).ready()`. That's been simplified a long time ago to just:

```
$(function() {
    // your code
});
```

In newer versions of jQuery, the shortcut event methods like `click()`, have been deprecated since they're redundant. In the latest versions they've been totally removed.

Instead, you need to use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for setting all event listeners.

```
$(".card__container--closed").on('click', function() {
    // ...
});
```

**UPDATE:** You've mentioned in the comments you're having the same `TypeError`s from the `.hide()` method. This is because it was removed in jQuery 3 as well since it often didn't play nicely with people's stylesheets. Instead, you can use `addClass()`, `removeClass()` and `toggleClass()` to add your own show/hide classes to the element. You'd then style those classes in your stylesheet so that you have full control over how showing and hiding is achieved.

Again, please read the [jQuery 3.0 Upgrade Guide](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/) since all your issues are based on outdated methods that jQuery 3 doesn't have anymore.

Comment: This has got me past the first hurdle - now I'm getting Uncaught TypeError: $(...).hide is not a function ???

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the jQuery 3 upgrade guide. The `.hide()` and `.show()` methods have also been removed in 3.0+ https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#effects

Comment: Instead you should use `.addClass()` so that you can apply your own hide/show styles that you know will always work.

Comment: You pass in a class name. Then style that class in your stylesheet. That way you have full control over how the element shows and hides itself.

Comment: @MichaelRoberts also, this is not a discussion forum. I believe my answer has solved your problem so now you have to go learn about the differences in jQuery 3 or downgrade to jQuery 2.

Comment: @MichaelRoberts don't forget to mark an answer correct.

Answer (score 0):

use the `document` or other `parent` selector before the dynamically created elements to trigger the events on that

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click',".card__container--closed",function () {
     $(document).find(".hide__overlay").css('display','none');
  });
});
```

Comment: This has got me past the first hurdle - now I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).hide is not a function` ???

Comment: If `hide` actually exists, this specific TypeError wouldn’t be possible.

Comment: Ok - the error has gone, but the div still remains...I'm not sure exactly what div I'm clicking on though so I think I'm targeting the wrong div for the on click event?? Is there anyway I could find out?

Comment: @MichaelRoberts please accept and upvote my answer if it works for you